# Automatically delete photo from Photo Stream when deleted in iPhoto or Aperture

Tags: iphone, photos.app, photos, photo-stream, aperture

After importing photos I quickly delete all the duplicate photos & bad ones. However they all still make their way to my Photo Stream and stay there even after I've pruned the bad photos.

Is there a way to automatically delete a photo in Photo Stream once it's been deleted in the Aperture or iPhoto library?

Comment: My guess is that if you delete *and* empty the trash (in iPhoto), then the pictures won't be synced. I will check it out later.

Answer (score 1):

Deleting the picture from *My Photo Stream* instead of the imported versions in your computer should do the trick. To do so just:

1. Open the *My Photo Stream* view in either iPhoto or Aperture.
2. Select the pictures to delete.
3. Press the Delete key and click *Delete*.

Comment: That means that in Order to delete each photo I have to delete it twice.

1. Delete it from my library.
2. Switch to Photo Stream
3. Search for photo again
4. Delete same photo again

Comment: @Achille How are you importing them? As you could delete them *before* the actual import to your computer.

Comment: @Thecafremo It would be nice if we always remembered to do it in that order... but it would also be nice if there were a solution that didn't require that. For example, I have a large library of personal photos that I'm only now finding the time to clean up and prune. I've already synced my phone many times, so I have lots of photos both in Photo Stream and locally.

Answer (score 0):

Tracking this back to the root makes me think disabling iPhoto's automatic download/import will solve the issue.

You can still keep the Photostream enabled, but you would have control to highlight the photos in it that you actually want to import and click 'Import Photo.' Or, highlight all the photos you don't ever want in Photostream, delete them from the Photostream, then afterwards highlight everything an select 'Import.'

Yes it's a bit more manual, but there aren't a lot of shades of gray with iCloud.

I won't go as far as to suggest turning off Photostream though - it's an adequate last-resort backup, and when you delete photos from your iPhone camera roll, those photos won't actually come back to your iPhone, so there's no worry there.